# Using class type as template argument type when create class definition

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class BaseCmd like:

```
template<typename T>    
class BaseCmd {
public:
private:
  T m;
};
```

and then derived class Cmd1:

```
class Cmd1 : public BaseCmd<Cmd1::A> {
public:
  struct A {
    int c, d;
  };
};
```

but I'm getting error:

```
error: incomplete type ‘Cmd1‘ used in nested name specifier
```

Is it even possible to define it like that? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the struct A cannot be used during the definition of the class. What would be the issue with defining A outside of Cmd1? If it is scope or clearity, maybe namespaces would be preferable here.

Comment: It may help to show what you want `BaseCmd` to _really do_.  Helping you to inherit from a base class that only holds a private variable that is not yet defined may be too abstract to help with your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a member of type `Cmd1::A` before `Cmd1` is complete. The simple fix is to define `A` outside of `Cmd1`. However, if for whatever reason you want to define `A` inside `Cmd1` you can add a layer of indierction like this:

```
template<typename T>    
class BaseCmd {
public:
private:
  T m;
};


class Cmd1 {
public:
  struct A {
    int c, d;
  };
  struct impl : public BaseCmd<A> {};
};
```

`Cmd1::impl` can inherit from `A` because `A`s definition is complete by the time `BaseCmd<A>` is used as base class.